# Change image style in simpleCaptcha

Tags: java, html, css, servlets, captcha

I am using simpleCatcha plugin for my java application. The captcha image that is generating is no readable so I want to change the image style. Is there any way to customize or change the style of the image. HTML is :

```
<img id="captcha" src="<c:url value="simpleCaptcha.jpg" />" width="150">
```

web.xml is :

```
<display-name>captcha</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SimpleCaptcha</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>nl.captcha.servlet.SimpleCaptchaServlet</servlet-class>      
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SimpleCaptcha</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/simpleCaptcha.jpg</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>simpleCaptcha.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

And page import is :

```
<%@ page import="nl.captcha.Captcha"%>
```

And I have used [this](http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/java/jsp/captcha.html) plugin for captcha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the source code for `nl.captcha.servlet.SimpleCaptchaServlet`, `width` , `height` and `FontColors` have been predefined. This can be found in simplecaptcha-1.1.1.jar. Below screen shot for your reference.

[image: SimpleCaptchaServlet]

Regarding the edges word renderers, this is handled in `ColoredEdgesWordRenderer` class & others which does some calculation on `xBaseline`, `yBaseline` , `shape` etc and arrives an angle at which the words of the captcha should be shown.

My bet is to achieve what you want, you either need to edit the source code and make a jar of your own and redeploy. This is because parameters are not taken from `web.xml` file.
Or look out for some other captcha code which you think is easier to identify text. But, suggestion is, the more complicated your captcha looks, the more security it will add.

[image: ColoredEdges]

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `SimpleCaptchaServlet` using your own servlet and use that instead. Then you should be able to remove and change the background or noise or borders

Example:

```
.addBackground(new FlatColorBackgroundProducer(Color.LIGHT_GRAY))
```

or

```
GradiatedBackgroundProducer bg = new GradiatedBackgroundProducer();
bg.setFromColor(Color.white);
bg.setToColor(Color.yellow);
.addBackground(bg)
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still looking for a solution, extend SimpleCaptchaServlet like below and map this new servlet in web.xml. This works for me

```
public class MySimpleCaptcha extends SimpleCaptchaServlet {

    private static final String PARAM_HEIGHT = "height";
    private static final String PARAM_WIDTH = "width";
    protected int _width = 200;
    protected int _height = 50;

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Captcha captcha = new Captcha.Builder(_width, _height)
            .addText()
            .addBackground(new GradiatedBackgroundProducer())

            // Add here whatever you need

            .addNoise()
            .gimp(new DropShadowGimpyRenderer())
            .addBorder()
            .build();

        CaptchaServletUtil.writeImage(resp, captcha.getImage());
        req.getSession().setAttribute(NAME, captcha);
     }

 }
```